# Product of a diagonal matrix with all positive entries and a quadratic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

I have a diagonal matrix D with all positive entries on diagonal and a quadratic matrix $A=B^{T}B$, is the product of the two matrices $C=DA$ also positive definite? or does the product has other properties? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try some very simple ($2\times 2$) examples for $D$ when $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\  1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ (i.e. the all ones matrix)

Comment: $A$ considered here is positive definite, is the result also positive definite and I'm wondering is there any simple proof for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The product doesn't have to be positive definite. For a simple counterexample take any positive semidefinite $A$ (any positive semidefinite $A$ can be written as $B^T B$). Then take $D$ to be the identity matrix and
$$
C = DA = IA = A
$$
is not positive definite.

**Edit**
The product need not be positive semidefinite either. For the product to be positive semidefinite one would require $DA$ to be a symmetric matrix. However, this is the case iff $A$ and $D$ commute, i.e. $[A,D]=0$. Which will not be the case for most choices of $A$ and $D$. You will however still have that the eigenvalues of $DA$ are all non-negative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about the conclusion that the product is positive semi-definite?

Comment: @ChasonYoung No, the product need not be PSD either. I've updated the answer to add some details.

Comment: Thanks so much for the updated detailed answer. Yes, I can draw that the eigenvalues of the product are all non-negative. Then, I want to ask for this case can I say $u^{T} DA u \geq 0$? Or if I give the additional condition that $B$ is of full rank, can I say that the resultant product is positive definite?

Comment: No for the product to be PD you also need it to be symmetric so the same argument holds.

Comment: How about the matrix form is $$BAB^{T}$$ where A is the diagonal matrix with all positive entries? Thanks!